# Stored procedure stopped when Browser closed

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

A long running process (SQL stored procedure) is started by calling **ExecuteSqlCommandAsync**. The stored procedure returns data as long as I have the browser up and running. When the browser is closed, the stored procedure stop or rollbacks. Is this the expected behavior? If I have to run a long running process, what should I do to make sure the long running process will run.?

Comment: "If I have to run a long running process" then create a long running service. OR maybe fix the real problem: slow running proc.

Comment: Do you mean what I see is the expected behavior for running a stored proc through browser? When you said "long running service", should I go for windows service or sql service which can keep running even though I close the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure that needs to be called can be wrapped in a SSIS package, and the web app can call the SSIS package directly will help to run the stored procedure as task. The Browser can be closed but still the task will run.